# How to bind nested list item in collectionview in xamarin

Tags: xamarin, collectionview

I am new in xamarin. I am getting difficulty to bind my List in xamarin CollectionView.
I get the bellow json from API

```
{
  "OK": 200,
  "status": "success",
  "data": [
    {     
      "Category": "Category 1",
      "List": [
        {
          "SubItem": "The A1"
        },
         {
          "SubItem": "The A2"
        }
      ]
    },
    {     
      "Category": "Category 2",
      "List": [
        {
          "SubItem": "The C1 sub"
        },
         {
          "SubItem": "The C2 sub"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: What do you want to do exactly?

Comment: use a grouped ListView

Comment: Thanks for suggesting grouped option @jason

Comment: Does my solution work for you? If yes, can you please accept it (click the ☑️ in the upper left corner of this answer ) so that we can help more people with same problem:).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have two models and a viewModel like this in your project:

```
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        BindingContext = new viewModel();
}

public class subModel
{
    public string SubItem { get; set; }
}
public class Data
{
    public string Category { get; set; }
    public IList<subModel> List { get; set; }

}

public class viewModel {

   public ObservableCollection<Data> items = new ObservableCollection<Data>();

    public viewModel() { 
        
    }

}
```

In the xaml, bind to a [grouped CollectionView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/collectionview/grouping#display-grouped-data):

```
<CollectionView ItemsSource="{Binding items}"
            IsGrouped="true">

    <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Label Text="{Binding SubItem}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>

    <CollectionView.GroupHeaderTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Label Text="{Binding Category}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </CollectionView.GroupHeaderTemplate>
</CollectionView>
```